# Escaping HTML in a Java Play Framework Scala Template

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

Using a Scala template within the Java Play framework 2.0, I want to output dynamic content as HTML encoded.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#@field.getId()").fieldList({
        data: "@myUnencodedData"
    })
</script>
```

Are there built in methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, HTML is escaped for security reasons. To output HTML, you wrap it in the Html helper: `@Html(myUnencodedData)`.