# typeahead bootstrap + play framework - Why do I need to HTML encode single quote characters in JSON being passed to HTML?

Tags: html, scala, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0, bootstrap-typeahead

## Storytime

In Play's templating scheme, I have this simplified setup:

```
@(param:String)    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    <head><!-- JQuery & Bootstrap css+js includes --></head>    <body> 
    @param    
    <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='@Html(param)' data-items="4">
</body>    </html>
```

The @Html() is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318819/escaping-html-in-a-java-play-framework-scala-template) and the bottom of [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates) and basically prevents characters like `<` from being replaced with `&lt;`. I'm attempting to pass in a `Json.stringify`-ed and `Json.toJson`-ed `List[String]` that I get from my database into the HTML through Play's template engine, and then have Bootstrap pick it up automatically from the `data-source` attribute.

Say @param evaluates to a JSON object that contains a string with a `'`:

```
<input data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["can't","hi","boom"]' data-items="4" type="text" >
```

I realized that the single quote characters needed to be escaped in my data-source JSON object. At first I experimented with using `\` and even `\\\` to no avail. I even set out to write a regex replacer for the task to emulate the addSlashes() mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764679/guide-to-proper-escaping-in-play-framework)

Then on a whim...

```
<input data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["can&#x27;t","hi", "boom"]' data-items="4" type="text" >
```

Everything works normally now! (when the data-source is hardcoded. Still need to figure out how to unescape @Html() so that `&#x27;` doesn't disappear.)

## Question

Why does Bootstrap Typeahead need to read in the data-source with the single-quote characters unescaped?

### For posterity:

```
val quoteRegex = """'""".r
quoteRegex.replaceAllIn(str, m => "&#x27;")
```

Comment: `single-quote characters unescaped?` don't you mean html encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the single quotes is that it truncates your data-source attribute. The html parser is going to read your html and give you something like

```
<input data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["can' t","hi","boom"]' data-items="4" type="text" >
```

and your data-source attribute will have a value of `["can`. So the problem isn't typeahead.

When you encode the single quote it no longer breaks the attribute and the encoded quote is added to the dom unencoded so you get the `'` instead of `&#x27;`

Comment: Then how does `&#x27;` get parsed as a single quote character when it's read by the Typeahead plugin? Is this just how jQuery works?

Comment: `&#x27;` get converted to `'`, html entities are converted to their equivalent characters

Comment: I guess jQuery just reads in html entities as their equivalent characters then o_o I think what I'm actually trying to grasp is "How does jQuery work"