# play framework template engine - can I escape HTML decoding inside of an @Html()?

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

See [this question for the full story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100892/typeahead-bootstrap-play-framework-why-do-i-need-to-html-encode-single-quote).

This is what I have:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='@Html(param)' data-items="4">
```

Say @param evaluates to `[&quot;can&#x27;t&quot;,&quot;hi&quot;, &quot;boom&quot;]` without the @Html() escaping, and `["can't","hi", "boom"]` with @Html().

Is it possible for me to call @Html(parameter) here but escape the conversion from `&#x27;` to `'` ?

Comment: The short answer is no. For security reasons, everything inside a `@Html` tag will get converted. Is there a reason you'd like to do this? Maybe you could let it convert then use jquery/javascript to substitute all single quotes with `&#x27;`

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this was because I didn't understand how Typeahead worked, and what part of the plugin was getting the contents of the data-source attribute. Then I learned that AJAX exist, so I'm now using that to get data from my database to typeahead and not passing information to Typeahead via the data-source attribute and Play's HTML template engine, but through the parameters to Typeahead.

Comment: For typeahead, you might want to take a look at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)